# How do I actually enable Twitter or Google auth in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm dropped into a scenario where I have to use DNN. So I created a vanilla site for testing/learning purposes (DNN 8.0.4 in this case), signed in as host, and went to "Available Extensions" and installed the Twitter and Google authentication systems. I can see under "Installed Extensions" | "Authentication Systems" that both are enabled. But I see no way to add client tokens or any other more specific config. Also, I created a sign-in page and dropped in the Account Login module--but again, no settings that I can see to actually choose which auth providers I want to use. It's either the default DNN or nothing.

How do I actually get some sort of UI where I can click the link to sign in via Google or Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course after hours of searching, it only takes a few minutes after posting the question to figure it out. Turns out there is an **admin** extensions page as well (it's under Advanced Settings in the Admin menu) and I then have to setup and enable the options there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason for this.

DNNCon supports multiple sites or portals.  Enabling those other authentication systems in Host settings makes
Keys them available to all portals.  They then can be enabled on a portal by portal basis in each portal’s Admin settings,